# Changing page layout from portrait to landscape using ArcPy with ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, layouts

I need my script to access the Page Orientation property of the current MXD, and switch it from portrait to landscape (or back).

I've looked through the ArcGIS 10 arcpy and arcpy.mapping documentation, and haven't had any luck.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This becomes easy in ArcGIS Pro where, since at least ArcGIS Pro 1.4.1 (and probably earlier), the [Layout class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layout-class.htm) has Read and Write [Properties](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layout-class.htm#P_GUID-6DFB661B-D50A-4E3A-AE75-6884442AD100) for `pageHeight` and `pageWidth` to set a layout's page height and based on the current `pageUnits`.

Answer (score 6):

Sadly the answer is no. sorry

Even from ESRI Staff:

*"There are currently no properties to read/change the page size using arcpy.mapping. As a workaround, you could create MXDs for each page size and oreintation you needed. The closest example I can think of is the **"Creating a map book with facing pages"** help topic. It doesnt use different pages sizes, however, it does use two MXDs, one for right facing pages, one for left facing pages. In your case, you may have one MXD for letter size, and one MXD for legal size, as an example."*

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/10361-change-Page-and-Print-Setup-from-ArcPy?p=32342#post32342

Possible Workaround is:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s90000002p000000.htm

Answer (score 5):

Can't do it yet in 10.0 from `arcpy.mapping`, going to have to use .Net or comtypes.

Comment: I can change the page orientation using only hotkeys. Would there be a way to simulate keypresses in my python script?

Comment: http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/