# WorkspaceFactory not defined in Python comtypes for ArcObjects?

Tags: arcpy, python, arcmap, arcobjects

I'm trying to programmatically export a symbolized raster to an RGB TIF using ArcGIS, i.e.: perform the equivalent of *Export Raster Data* in ArcMap with *Use Renderer* and *Force RGB* activated.

I followed the beginning of [Use python to disable "Scale map elements proportionally to changes in page size"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178532) to access ArcObjects in Python.

I'm trying to re-create [the code in this discussion](https://community.esri.com/thread/46133) to eventually create a *RasterLayerExport* object. Before that, though, I find myself incapable of creating a *WorkspaceFactory*.

I tried running:

```
import arcpy

from snippets102 import *
from comtypes.client import GetModule, CreateObject

import comtypes.gen.esriFramework as esriFramework
import comtypes.gen.esriArcMapUI as esriArcMapUI
import comtypes.gen.esriCarto as esriCarto
import comtypes.gen.esriDisplay as esriDisplay
import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase

wkspf = CreateObject(esriGeoDatabase.WorkspaceFactory, interface = esriGeoDatabase.IWorkspaceFactory)
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/AndyPL/.PyCharmCE2017.2/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 14, in <module>
    wkspf = CreateObject(esriGeoDatabase.WorkspaceFactory, interface=esriGeoDatabase.IWorkspaceFactory)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 238, in CreateObject
    obj = comtypes.CoCreateInstance(clsid, clsctx=clsctx, interface=interface)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 1225, in CoCreateInstance
    _ole32.CoCreateInstance(byref(clsid), punkouter, clsctx, byref(iid), byref(p))
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 945, in GetResult
WindowsError: [Error -2147221164] Class not registered
```

Odd, since creating a *PlugInWorkspaceFactory* works fine. Does anyone else get this error?

Comment: This is one of the odd ones, you create an IWorkspaceFactory from the workspace type: AccessWorkspaceFactory for personal GDB, FileGDBWorkspaceFactory for file GDB etc.. see the coclasses at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000m9w000000 and look at the example http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00490000005m000000 for ShapefileWorkspaceFactory (ctrl + F to find it). Clearly on line 11 of the example the workspacefactory is being created as RasterWorkspaceFactory.

Comment: Thanks (again) for your answer Michael. So would it be something like `wkspf = CreateObject(esriGeoDatabase.RasterWorkspaceFactory, interface = esriGeoDatabase.IWorkspaceFactory)`?

Comment: The RasterWorkspaceFactory is in DataSourcesRaster, see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001q0000091p000000 I'm not sure what the arcpy import is for that, presumably import comtypes.gen.esriDataSourcesRaster as esriDataSourcesRaster. Were I certain of this I would have posted an answer; When you sort this out can you post your working code as an answer to your own question, I too would be interested to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Michael Stimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/15054/michael-stimson) for figuring this one out.

In this specific example, what I needed was a *RasterWorkspaceFactory*, and not a *WorkspaceFactory*.

```
from snippets102 import *
from comtypes.client import GetModule, CreateObject

import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase
import comtypes.gen.esriDataSourcesRaster as esriDataSourcesRaster

wkDir = "C:/YourWorkspace/"

wkspf = CreateObject(esriDataSourcesRaster.RasterWorkspaceFactory, interface=esriGeoDatabase.IWorkspaceFactory)
wksp = wkspf.OpenFromFile(wkDir, 0)
```

I'm afraid I still don't know how to access *WorkspaceFactory*, though.

Comment: There is no WorkspaceFactory (generic), this is a very odd object in that the IWorkspaceFactory interface is initialized with a CoClass *only*. Normaly an interface is initialized with the same class, IPoint for example is initialized to PointClass() in C# esriGeometry.Point in python. Another example of this odd instantiation is IPointCollection, there is no PointCollection class, the interface is initialized as one of the CoClasses (Ring, Path, Multipoint etc..).